# Failed to execute Contains using Shadow Root

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use my shadow root and see if it contains an H1 which should read false. But for some reason instead I am receiving this Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute contains on Node: parameter 1 is not of type Node.

Where am I going wrong?

http://plnkr.co/edit/4kgfy05cXuZ9Jefjx01w?p=preview

```js
var root = document.querySelector('div').createShadowRoot();
root.innerHTML = '<content select="h1"></content>';
      
//console.log(document.querySelector('h1'));
//console.log(document.querySelector('content h1'));
console.log(root.querySelector('content').contains('h1'));
```

```html
<h1>Header defined in the light DOM</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'h1'` is a string, not a Node. You need to pass in an object! Create an `h1`, `document.createElement("h1");` and pass it in that way.

[`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)

Sample:

Either cache the variable with `var derp = document.createElement("h1");` or:

```
console.log(root.querySelector('content').contains(document.createElement('h1'))); //contains(element);
```